# How can I create automatic translations to my java file, by using strings.xml

Tags: java, android, string, translation

A month ago I started to learn the basics of Android Studio, and I am making an app at the moment. The original language of the app English, but I also wanted it to be in Dutch. I know how to translate the strings.xml file, but I have a hard time translating the words that are in Java. I tried using all the things listed on here, or anywhere on google, but either my app crashes, or in stead of even the English word, there appears a number. So I am wondering, how can I translate the words (one, two and three) that are in my app, (maybe by using strings.xml?)x

public class view_favourite extends Fragment {

```
public view_favourite() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

SQLiteDatabase db;
int [] fav_array=  new int[60];
int updated=0;

private static final int START_LEVEL = 1;
private int mLevel;
private Button mNextLevelButton;
private TextView mLevelTextView;

final String[] numberNames = {

        "First","Second","Third"
} ;
```

If I needed to upload more, sorry, I do not know how this all works and I have a lot to learn.
(I know favourite is spelled wrong :))

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/index.html

Comment: I'm thinking that any text you want to internationalize - anything that needs to appear to the user in English or in Dutch - probably shouldn't be coded as a Java string literal in the first place.  Q: Am I mistaken?  Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538260/ and here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well but it all gave errors.

Comment: Hmm, then I think I should start deleting it all and throw it in somewhere else. I don't like it to be almost perfect, I want it all. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question correctly. Here's how to get string from resources in java code. If you have files with translation, the string will be one of them.

```
public class Test extends Fragment {

void test(){
    String first = getString(getContext(), R.string.first);
    String second = getString(getContext(), R.string.second);
    String third = getString(getContext(), R.string.third);
}

String getStringFromResources(Context context, int stringId){
    return context.getString(stringId);
}
}
```